# Can tree frogs modulate their infrared output?

Tags: science, biology, jurassic-world

In Jurassic World one of the scientists said that tree frogs can modulate their infrared output. Is this science fiction or science fact?

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I wonder if it might be more appropriate on Biology.SE

Comment: You're right. It is an interesting question!

Comment: Other people are going to be searching for this information online. Do we want them to go to biology.se or join the conversation here? Is it against the rules to overlap? Edit - it's not. It's sci-fi but may also be sci-fa.

Comment: I feel this should be migrated to biology se... If there's not equivalent question there...

Comment: We don't not close/migrate questions just because we want to attract new users. Ask about tree frogs within the JP/JW universe, and it's on-topic here; ask about real-life biology of tree frogs, and it's not.

Comment: In response to the "on hold" reason stated above, the question seeking a scientific solution IS related directly to a cited work of fiction, namely, the film entitled Jurassic World, and is a contributing factor to an important part of the plot in said film. I imagine I'll be shouted down for this since I'm fairly new and all, but I see no reason why this question can't be taken off hold and be allowed to be answered.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 because they're not asking about frogs specific to the work, the question is just inspired by them. if you remove the mention of JW, the question has absolutely nothing to do with SF/F.

Comment: But it does have something to do with the work. Surely that's the key thing which makes this question OK to answer?

Comment: @phantom42 what if there was a movie about a math contest and in one of the contestants backstory he is told by a high school math genius that pi is 3.15 instead of 3.14 and at his math contest that information causes him to lose? I understand what you're saying but this tidbit of information could be relevant. I don't know if there is a name for this in writing. But I don't know right now if it is. And possibly there may be other viewers as anal as me out there that might want to know as well. probably not tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract from wikipedia article on [Multi-spectral camouflage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-spectral_camouflage):

"The English zoologist **Hugh Cott**, in his 1940 book Adaptive Coloration in Animals, wrote that some caterpillars such as the eyed hawk-moth **Smerinthus ocellatus**, and tree frogs such as the **red-snouted treefrog Hyla coerulea**, are coloured so as to blend with their backgrounds whether observed **in visible light or in infra-red**." (emphasys mine)

On the article there are documentation links referencing the appropiate bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

According to this 1977 paper, some Glass frogs are infrared camouflaged. They can't manipulate this, but is just a natural trait of their skin. Some frogs can camouflage themselves like chameleons though.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/22295078_Infrared_reflectance_in_leaf_sitting_Neotropical_frogs

"Two members of the glass-frog family Centrolenidae (Centrolenella fleischmanni, C. prosoblepon) and the hylid subfamily Phyllomedusinae (Agalychnis moreletii, Pachymedusa dacnicolor) reflect near-infrared light (700 to 900 nanometers) when examined by infrared color photography. Infrared reflectance may confer adaptive advantage to these arboreal frogs both in thermoregulation and infrared cryptic coloration."